# Efficient design pattern to perform a one-to-one mappings from a type hierarchy to set of values

Tags: java, design-patterns, polymorphism

I would like to call an external vendor's api method on types in my local library. The vendor's method takes a setting in the form of a string which can take on several values, say `"Cat"` and `"Dog"`. I am performing the mapping from my type to the vendor's setting string thus:

```
public class Program {
    interface LocalType {}
    static class LocalCat implements LocalType {}
    static class LocalDog implements LocalType {}

    // Calls some API to get the animal's sound
    interface AnimalSounds {
        void playSound(LocalType t);
    }

    // Vendor-specific implementation
    static class VendorSounds implements AnimalSounds{
        private static VendorAPI api = new VendorAPI();
        @Override public void playSound(LocalType t) {
            // Map local type to vendor setting
            if (t instanceof LocalCat)
                api.vendorMethod("Cat");
            else if (t instanceof LocalDog)
                api.vendorMethod("Dog");

        }
    }

    // API defined externally by vendor (reproduced here for illustration)
    static class VendorAPI {
        static void vendorMethod(String type) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnimalSounds s = new VendorSounds(); // Choose vendor
        s.playSound(new LocalCat()); // For example
    }
}
```

Here `"Cat"` and `"Dog"` are vendor-specific settings; I may later change to a French vendor where these two are `"Chat"` and `"Chien"`, respectively. So to avoid adding vendor-specific information to the `LocalType` hierarchy which would then have to change each time I change vendors, I hid this mapping in a sort of adapter `AnimalSounds` (I added `VendorSounds` as an example for one vendor).

But the cascade of `instanceof` smells like poor design to me, is there perhaps a more elegant way of accomplishing this which I have overlooked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to keep the mapping completely outside of your local types, you could build a `Map<Class,String>`, and use it instead of a chain of `instanceof`-based conditionals:

```
static final Map<Class,String> vendorMethodMap = new HashMap<>;
static {
    // The data for this map could come from a configuration file of sorts
    vendorMethodMap.put(LocalCat.class, "Cat");
    vendorMethodMap.put(LocalDog.class, "Dog");
}
```

Now your `playSound` method would look like this:

```
@Override public void playSound(LocalType t) {
    api.vendorMethod(vendorMethodMap.get(t.getClass()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this in a more general way, you can use the ***visitor pattern***. The concrete element classes accept classes implementing a visitor interface:

```
public class Program {

    interface LocalTypeVisitor {
        void visit(LocalDog dog);
        void visit(LocalCat cat);
    }

    interface LocalType {
        void accept(LocalTypeVisitor visitor);
    }
    static class LocalCat implements LocalType {
        @Override public void accept(LocalTypeVisitor visitor) {
            visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }
    static class LocalDog implements LocalType {
        @Override public void accept(LocalTypeVisitor visitor) {
            visitor.visit(this);
        }
    }

    // API defined externally by vendor (reproduced here for illustration)
    static class VendorAPI {
        void vendorMethod(String type) {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    interface Vendor extends LocalTypeVisitor {}

    // Vendor-specific implementation
    static class VendorSounds implements Vendor {
        private static VendorAPI api = new VendorAPI();
        @Override public void visit(LocalCat cat) {
            api.vendorMethod("Cat");
        }
        @Override public void visit(LocalDog dog) {
            api.vendorMethod("Dog");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vendor s = new VendorSounds(); // Choose vendor
        new LocalCat().accept(s); // For example
    }
}
```

But it's harder to create new `LocalType` implementations, since it ripples through all visitors. So consider this with care.

Comment: by double-dispatching

Comment: I like this as it allows the visitor to potentially return a complex type rather than `void`